# python module for trace/chromatogram analysis

Tags: python, numpy, module, scipy

Is there a python module that integrates simple chromatogram/trace analysis algorithms? I am looking for baseline correction, peak detection and peak integration functionality for simple time-courses (with data stored in numpy arrays).

I spent quite some time searching now and there doesn't seem to be any which really surprises me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what analysis you are conducting but have you looked at [PyLSS](https://github.com/gmrandazzo/PyLSS) ?

It can (and I quote from the documentation):

> > > PyLSS is able to compute:
> > >
> > > > LSS parameters (log kw and S)
> > > >
> > > > Build and plot **chromatograms** from experimental/predicted retention times

Regarding peak detection and peak integration, I have used the functionality of the ptp() method in the Numpy module for this and I find that it is pretty powerful. Would this satisfy your requirement?